# C#: Is there a built-in equivalent of Func<>/Action<> that stores a function pointer as well as state?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am looking to call the same function with the same parameters repeatedly in a timer tick. I do not want to store these parameters as class variables in the form, as it does not need to change.

My current solution is:

```
    /// <summary>
/// This class is designed to bundle in data with a function pointer.
/// The function pointer is intended to be called repeatedly after leaving the context of the initial parameters.
/// </summary>
public class FunctionPointerWithState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The function pointer to call when issuing a search.
    /// </summary>
    private Action<object> Issuer;

    /// <summary>
    /// The parameter to send.
    /// </summary>
    private object Param;


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new object with the appropriate state.
    /// </summary>
    public SingleLobBurstSearch( Action<object> issuer, object prm )
    {
        Issuer = issuer;
        Param = prm;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Calls the stored function pointer with the stored state.
    /// </summary>
    public void IssueRequest()
    {
        Issuer( Param );
    }
}
```

"IssueRequest()" is called by the timer on each tick.  Is there a built-in language equivalent of this?

Thanks!  Also, please let me know if the question is not clear.

**EDIT:** I would like to do this without lambda expressions.

Comment: Any particular reason for not wanting to do it with lambdas?

Comment: I get resistance to lambda expressions because they are shorthand.  There is a large emphasis on readability in my workplace.  Some of my coworkers don't like lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what type of timer you're using. Since you mention forms, I'll assume you mean `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. You can set the Timer's [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tag.aspx) property to hold the values. Then, whenever the tick event occurs, you can get the values from that property.

If you're using [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), you can pass state information as the second parameter to the timer constructor. That information will be passed as the `State` parameter to the timer callback.

There doesn't appear to be a way to pass state information to the `Elapsed` event handler for [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

Comment: I am using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this just the essence of a closure?

```
Action MakeIssuer(SomeParam param)
{
    Action issuer = () => DoSomeWork(param);   
    return issuer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture them:

```
int i = 5;
myTimer.Tick += (s, e) => doStuff(i);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without anonymous methods?

Comment: @user664939 not that I can think of. You would have to find ways to conserve the pointers to the values. Like you did by making them global.

Comment: @user - not without storing 'i' in a class level variable which is what you asked to avoid.  (with anonymous methods the compiler essentially does that for you behind the scenes)

Answer (score 0):

the Timer class will get you there if milliseconds are close enough precision for you.  As part of the constructor you provide the method to call when the interval comes up.